# Named route not working with url

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a route that works perfectly

```
Route::get('downloadsPage', function()
{
$downloads = Download::get();   
return View::make('index', array('downloads' => $downloads));
});
Route::get('/buy/{id}', function($id)
{
$download = Download::find($id);    
return View::make('buy', array('download' => $download));
});
```

with a

```
return View::make('downloadsPage');
```

that is located in my controller.

```
public function afterSignin() {
    if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password')))) {
        return Redirect::intended('downloadsPage')->with('message', 'Thanks for signing in');
    }
```

The problem is I also have a nav view file for a link for the same route

```
<li><a href="{{ URL::route('downloadsPage')}}">Store</a></li>
```

and I get the error
http://postimg.org/image/bhxezsh3n/

The error is coming from not correctly setting the route in the view I think.

I also have a foreach loop in the main view that uses the parameters passed in the routes.

```
@foreach ($downloads as $download)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $download->name }}</td>
    <td>&pound;{{ round($download->price/100) }}</td>
    <td><a href="/buy/{{ $download->id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I am using named routes and am obviously missing something that is probably a simple fix.

I tried re-writing the routes and adding the respective controller functions with get and post and passing parameters but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a named route, a named route would be:

```
Route::get('downloadsPage', ['as' => 'downloadsPage', function()
{
    $downloads = Download::get();   
    return View::make('index', array('downloads' => $downloads));
}]);
```

Notice the `'as' => 'route.name'`, that is what defines the name of the route.

Read more in [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes).